# Colored diagonal divided table cell

Tags: tables, tabularx, colortbl, diagbox

How can I fill a table cell with different colors? I have tried the diagbox package but it doesn't work as you can see. I am not so much interested in the diagonal line. I only want to separate the cell in two triangles, put text in both triangles and fill them with different colors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{8cm}{|X|X|X|X|}
  \hline
  \diagbox{\cellcolor{red}Time}{\cellcolor{green}Day} & Mon & Tue & Wed\\
  \hline
  Morning & used & used &\\
  \hline
  Afternoon &  & used & used\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With mighty `tikz` and `tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2][]{
  \tikz[remember picture,inner sep=\tabcolsep,outer sep=0,baseline=(#1.base),align=left]{\node[minimum width=\hsize](#1){$#2$};}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{8cm}{|X|X|X|X|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|@{}X@{}|}{\tikzmark[a]{\raisebox{-1ex}{Time}\raisebox{1ex}{\hspace{1ex}Day}}} & Mon & Tue & Wed\\
  \hline
  Morning & used & used &\\
  \hline
  Afternoon &  & used & used\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path[fill=red,opacity=0.2](a.north west)--(a.south west) -- (a.south east) -- cycle;
\path[fill=green,opacity=0.2](a.north east)--(a.south east) -- (a.north west) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `overlay`, it is difficult to set the background. You can draw the nodes once again instead (though it looks ugly)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2][]{
  \tikz[remember picture,inner sep=\tabcolsep,outer sep=0pt,baseline=(#1.base),align=left]{\node[minimum width=\hsize](#1){$#2$};}
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{8cm}{|X|X|X|X|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|@{}X@{}|}{\tikzmark[a]{\raisebox{-2.5ex}{Time}\raisebox{1ex}{\hspace{0.9ex}Day}}} & text text text text & Tue & Wed\\
  \hline
  Morning & used & used &\\
  \hline
  Afternoon &  & used & used\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path[fill=red,opacity=1](a.north west)--(a.south west) -- node [pos=.5, above left=0.5ex and -0.75ex] {Time}(a.south east) -- cycle ;
\path[fill=green,opacity=1](a.north west)-- node [pos=.5, below right=0.5ex and 0.1ex] {Day}(a.north east)-- (a.south east)  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the `ex` values suitably.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is that this solution only works if the "Time/Day" cell is the "biggest" cell. In my "real-world" table this is sometimes not the case. You can see the problem by replacing "Mon" with "text text text text" in the table above. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Thanks, but there is still one little problem. The background color in the multi-color cell is transparent. Is it possible to set opacity=1 and say Tikz to fill only the background?

Comment: @user4811 See the edited answer.

Comment: It is also possible to do it without tikzmark http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149011/fill-a-table-cell-with-empty-lines, but your solution have brought me on the right track. Thx for your help!

Comment: Nope, it also works with tabularx. The trick is to draw an empty Tikz node which just reserves the space. Then you can put whatever you want in this node.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabularX}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical environment `{tabularx}` (of the eponymous package) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns. It's possible to use these nodes with Tikz to draw or fill whatever you want in the tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{8cm}{XXXX}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \fill [red!15] (1-|1) |- (2-|2) -- cycle ;
     \fill [green!15] (1-|1) -| (2-|2) -- cycle ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\Body
  \diagbox{Time}{Day} & Mon  & Tue  & Wed  \\
  Morning             & used & used &      \\
  Afternoon           &      & used & used \\
\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]